# Plot of $\sin(x^x)$ is missing from $x=143$

Tags: plotting, machine-precision

When plotting the graph of $\sin(x^x)$ I noticed that there is no plot from about $x=143$. I don't suppose there is a purely mathematical explanation for this?

So, why is there no graph in *Mathematica* from $x=143$? Some kind of overflow?

```
f[x_] = Sin[x^x]
Plot[{f[x]}, {x, 142, 144}, PlotStyle -> Thin, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Related: [(3152)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3152/121), [(104815)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104815/121)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Normally `Plot` uses machine precision numbers; your $x^x$ expression is hitting the limit of the numbers that can be represented in machine precision right about $x>143$.

Note:

```
Solve[$MaxMachineNumber == x^x, x]

(* Out: {{x -> 143.016}} *)
```

---

You can increase the `WorkingPrecision` setting for `Plot` adequately, and the plot will be complete:

```
f[x_] = Sin[x^x]
Plot[{f[x]}, {x, 142, 144}, PlotStyle -> Thin, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
      WorkingPrecision -> 450]
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSkAJ.png]